# Remove a value from a cell based on another value of the same row in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i have a data set presented as follow:
[FORMAT TO CONVERT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPsf1.png)

I would like to classify values in part name and material column based on their value in ID but I am confused about the code to use in python. I know it is a conditional code but I don't know which one to use exactly. The  final result should look like this [final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw76d.png)

Comment: Please do no use images of data, provide a DataFrame constructor: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this ?

```
df['Part name']=np.where(df['ID']=='P',df['Part name'],np.nan)
df['Material']=np.where(df['ID']=='M',df['Material'],np.nan)
```